# Como puedo almacenar el contenido de un documento en un array de char

Tags: c, archivo, fopen, busqueda

El código que tengo para buscar coincidencias con el patron "pat" actualmente es este:

```
int main()
{        
char pat[] = "porompomrom";
char txt[] = "lorem ipsum ipsum lorem porompomrom prompo ipsum..."
    int q = 101; // A prime number
    search(pat, txt, q);
    return 0;
}
```

Y estoy intentado que la variable "txt" de la parte superior almacene el texto (flujoB)

```
 FILE *flujoB = fopen("text.txt", "rt+");
    if(flujoB == NULL) {
            perror("Error, el documento no se ha encontrado");
            return 1;
    }
```

Comment: entonces... ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Qué es eso de *igualar un documento*? ¿No será que lo que pretendes realmente es leer el contenido de un archivo?

Comment: Lo que deseo es almacenar el contenido de un documento de texto en la variable "txt"

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para aclarar el motivo de la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si eres capaz de delimitar el tamaño máximo del contenido del archivo puedes hacer algo tal que:

```
int txt[200]; // máximo 199 caracteres

FILE *flujoB = fopen("text.txt", "r");
fgets(txt, 200, flujoB);
fclose(flujoB);
```